# What projects need to reference the .Net Standard Library in a Cross Platform Solution

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, .net-standard

I am building a Cross Platform Application. A `Xamarin Forms` .Net Standard library with 3 implementations on Android, iOS and UWP.

I realise I have to reference the [.Net Standard nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NETStandard.Library/) to build a .Net Standard Cross Platform project

This nuget is currently refrenced by my Xamarin.Forms Application (Through the .net Standard SDK) and also by my Android and iOS projects.

Now my question is, do the Android and iOS projects need to reference the .Net Standard library - I can't understand why they would.

I can't find any documentation on this to help me understand and I also don't want to be referencing more libraries than I have to on my project bulking up the packages

Comment: Try to remove this reference and see if it still works?

Comment: Only the .NET Standard SDK style project should use the NETStandard.Library NuGet package. This will be implicitly referenced by the .NET Standard project - you do not need to add an explicit reference by installing it into the .NET Standard project. The other iOS and Android projects just need to reference the .NET Standard project.

Comment: @MattWard Thanks for the answer, I have tested it and you are correct. If you would like to post as an answer I will mark it as correct. Out of interrest is there any documentation for this? as the .Net Standard nuget does have `Xamarin.iOS` and `Xamarin.Android` implementations and depdendencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the .NET Standard SDK style project should use the NETStandard.Library NuGet package. This will be implicitly referenced by the .NET Standard project - you do not need to add an explicit reference to this NuGet package by installing it into the .NET Standard project.

The other iOS and Android projects just need to reference the .NET Standard project.